# How to show progress hud while compressing a file in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, zip, progress-bar, swift4, hud

I'm using [marmelroy/Zip framework](https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip) to zip/unzip files in my project, and [JGProgressHUD](https://github.com/JonasGessner/JGProgressHUD) to show the progress of the operation.

I'm able to see the HUD if I try to show it from the ViewDidLoad method, but if I use it in the closure associated to the progress feature of the quickZipFiles method (like in the code sample), the hud is shown just at the end of the operation.

I guess this could be related to a timing issue, but since I'm not too much into completion handlers, closures and GDC (threads, asynchronous tasks, etc.) I would like to ask for a suggestion.

Any ideas?

```
// In my class properties declaration
var hud = JGProgressHUD(style: .dark)

// In my ViewDidLoad
self.hud.indicatorView = JGProgressHUDPieIndicatorView()
self.hud.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.7)

// In my method
do {
    self.hud.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("Zipping files...", comment: "Zipping File Message")
    self.hud.detailTextLabel.text = "0%"
    if !(self.hud.isVisible) {
        self.hud.show(in: self.view)
    }
    zipURL = try Zip.quickZipFiles(documentsList, fileName: "documents", progress: { (progress) -> () in
        let progressMessage = "\(round(progress*100))%"
        print(progressMessage)
        self.hud.setProgress(Float(progress), animated: true)
        self.hud.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("Zipping files...", comment: "Zipping File Message")
        self.hud.detailTextLabel.text = progressMessage
        if (progress == 1.0) {
            self.hud.dismiss()
        }
    })
} catch {
    print("Error while creating zip...")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the implementation of the zip library, all of the zipping/unzipping and the calls to the progress handlers are being done on the same thread. The example shown on the home page isn't very good and can't be used as-is if you wish to update the UI with a progress indicator while zipping or unzipping.

The solution is to perform the zipping/unzipping in the background and in the progress block, update the UI on the main queue.

Assuming you are calling your posted code from the main queue (in response to the user performing some action), you should update your code as follows:

```
// In my class properties declaration
var hud = JGProgressHUD(style: .dark)

// In my ViewDidLoad
self.hud.indicatorView = JGProgressHUDPieIndicatorView()
self.hud.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.7)

self.hud.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("Zipping files...", comment: "Zipping File Message")
self.hud.detailTextLabel.text = "0%"
if !(self.hud.isVisible) {
    self.hud.show(in: self.view)
}

DispatchQueue.global().async {
    defer {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.hud.dismiss()
        }
    }

    do {
        zipURL = try Zip.quickZipFiles(documentsList, fileName: "documents", progress: { (progress) -> () in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let progressMessage = "\(round(progress*100))%"
                print(progressMessage)
                self.hud.setProgress(Float(progress), animated: true)
                self.hud.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("Zipping files...", comment: "Zipping File Message")
                self.hud.detailTextLabel.text = progressMessage
            }
        })
    } catch {
        print("Error while creating zip...")
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! You saved me day!! Works like a charm. Thanks a lot. Since I see no native method to abort the compression operation (but the HUD permits some kind of interaction), do you have any idea about how I could handle an abortion of the compression thread?

Comment: The API of the zip library doesn't support any way to cancel.

Comment: Nope. And I was wondering if I could force it somehow, maybe canceling the thread or something like that.

Comment: There's no way to stop the zip but you could modify your code to stop updating the progress view and dismiss it if the user chooses to cancel. The zip will simply finish itself in the background as you let the user continue using the app.

Comment: Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type 'Progress?'

Answer (score 4):

[ZIP Foundation](https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation) comes with built-in support for progress reporting and cancelation.
So if you can switch ZIP library, this might be a better fit for your project.  (Full disclosure: I am the author of this library)

Here's some sample code that shows how you can zip a directory and display operation progress on a `JGProgressHUD`. I just zip the main bundle's directory here as example.

The ZIP operation is dispatched on a separate thread so that your main thread can update the UI. The `progress` var is a default [Foundation (NS)Progress](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/progress) object which reports changes via KVO.

```
import UIKit
import ZIPFoundation
import JGProgressHUD

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var progressLabel: UILabel!
    var indicator = JGProgressHUD()
    var isObservingProgress = false
    var progressViewKVOContext = 0

    @objc
    var progress: Progress?

    func startObservingProgress()
    {
        guard !isObservingProgress else { return }

        progress = Progress()
        progress?.completedUnitCount = 0
        self.indicator.progress = 0.0

        self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(progress.fractionCompleted), options: [.new], context: &progressViewKVOContext)
        isObservingProgress = true
    }

    func stopObservingProgress()
    {
        guard isObservingProgress else { return }

        self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(progress.fractionCompleted))
        isObservingProgress = false
        self.progress = nil
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == #keyPath(progress.fractionCompleted) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.indicator.progress = Float(self.progress?.fractionCompleted ?? 0.0)
                if let progressDescription = self.progress?.localizedDescription {
                    self.progressLabel.text = progressDescription
                }

                if self.progress?.isFinished == true {
                    self.progressLabel.text = ""
                    self.indicator.progress = 0.0
                }
            }
        } else {
            super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func cancel(_ sender: Any) {
        self.progress?.cancel()
    }

    @IBAction func createFullArchive(_ sender: Any) {
        let directoryURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL

        let tempArchiveURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString).appendingPathExtension("zip")
        self.startObservingProgress()
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            try? FileManager.default.zipItem(at: directoryURL, to: tempArchiveURL, progress: self.progress)
            self.stopObservingProgress()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas, I will definitely look into it asap.