# How to print progress with ZIPFoundation

Tags: swift, zipfoundation

How can I track and print progress percentage to console on each progress update using [ZIPFoundation](https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation) in a class file that is not a controller?

I am quite new to swift and I have been trying to understand how [Progress](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/progress) works for quite a long time because it seems like it can be used to track the progress of unzip process using ZIPFoundation module (unfortunately without a luck so far). For the info, the unzipping itself works fine for me.

As far as I know it should be something similar to this, but I am not sure how to track it:

```
class MyClass {
    @objc var unzipProgress: Progress?

func unzipFile(from: URL, to: URL) -> Bool {
        let fileManager = FileManager()
        
        print("Unzipping...")
        do {            
            // How to track unzipProgress?
            try fileManager.unzipItem(at: from, to: to, progress: unzipProgress)
            print("Extraction success from \(from.path) to \(to.path)")
        } catch {
            print("Extraction of ZIP archive failed with error:\(error)")
        }
    }
```

Edit: I am familiar with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48972943/how-to-show-progress-hud-while-compressing-a-file-in-swift-4) but it does not help me as it uses JGProgressHUD and a controller class.

Comment: It's unclear what you actually want to do with the progress. Please edit your question and provide what you specifically want to do.

Comment: @HangarRash I did update wording a bit, but I think the question is pretty obvious. How do I print progress percentage to console every time it changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for ZIPFoundation tells you [how to monitor progress](https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation#progress-tracking-and-cancellation).

You need to create a `Progress` object:

```
let unzipProgress = Progress()
```

Then you need to setup an observer for the `fractionCompleted` property:

```
let observation = unzipProgress.observe(\.fractionCompleted) { progress, _ in
  print("progress: ", progress.fractionCompleted)
}
```

Then pass in your `unzipProgress` to one of the zip methods:

```
try fileManager.unzipItem(at: from, to: to, progress: unzipProgress)
```

Then you can cleanup the observation:

```
observation.invalidate()
```

Your `unzipFile` function becomes something like this:

```
func unzipFile(from: URL, to: URL) -> Bool {
    let fileManager = FileManager()

    let unzipProgress = Progress()
    let observation = unzipProgress.observe(\.fractionCompleted) { progress, _ in
       print("Extraction progress: ", progress.fractionCompleted)
    }
    
    print("Unzipping...")
    do {            
        // How to track unzipProgress?
        try fileManager.unzipItem(at: from, to: to, progress: unzipProgress)
        print("Extraction success from \(from.path) to \(to.path)")
    } catch {
        print("Extraction of ZIP archive failed with error:\(error)")
    }

    observation.invalidate()
}
```

You can remove your `unzipProgress` property from your class since you only need the local variable.

Comment: Thank you! As I am new to swift it was observation part this time that was unclear to me.